# Flutter run works from command line but not with VsCode

Tags: flutter

I installed Flutter and I have a project that used it (Flutter Web).
As IDE I use VsCode.
When I run the app using command line (`flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`) it works well, instead when I use VsCode I get this error:

```
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'Future': InternalError: No frame with index 17.
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'that': InternalError: No frame with index 17.
...
```

[image]

I launch the app with fn+f5 and I created this `.vscode/launch.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Web nosound null",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "deviceId": "chrome",
      "args": [
        "--no-sound-null-safety"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Web sound null",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "deviceId": "chrome",
      "args": []
    },
  ]
}
```

I tried also `flutter clean` but nothing changes, also uninstall and reinstall Flutter seems not to solve the problem.
VsCode is updated.

What am I wrong?

Comment: Have you install Flutter and Dart from VSCode Extension?

Comment: @TrầnTrungHiếu What do you mean? I installed Flutter and Dart extension (as said here https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/vscode)

Comment: First, open VSCode. Next, click the icon with four squares on the left of the screen. And that's VSCode Extensions

Comment: @TrầnTrungHiếu I got Dart v3.36.0 and Flutter v3.36.0

Comment: Sorry, i don't know the solution to this problem